# Is it OK to have Hostname domain different than the Nameservers domain?

Tags: web-server, web-hosting, hostname

I was wondering if hostname domain and nameservers domain can be different on my server. I have always kept them the same but now that I am moving my server, I do not want my clients to have the trouble to change the NS records.

Now if the both domains are hosted on the same server and pointing proper A records to the same IP, would it help me achieve what I am wanting to? For example:

```
Hostname: srv.first-domain.com      A    1.1.100.1
NS1: ns1.second-domain.com          A    1.1.100.1
NS2: ns2.second-domain.com          A    1.1.100.1
```

Will really appreciate any help in this regard.

Comment: This is pretty normal when you use third party DNS server or when your company has more than one internal domain.

I didn't understand the second part of question "Now if the both domains are hosted on the same server  ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was wondering if hostname domain and nameservers domain can be different on my server.

Surely they can. There is nothing wrong as mentioned by @Alessandro Carini.
Let's make some quick research.

This is my personal [site](https://ptl.cloud). If we made some WHOIS lookup on it we will see that two lines:

```
Domain Name: ptl.cloud
Name Server: dns104.ovh.net
Name Server: ns104.ovh.net
```

To be honest this is default configuration shipped with domains bought on OVH.com

Comment: Yes that's what I did yesterday. Really appreciate all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your current configuration is not compliant with the DNS spec, which requires at least  2 name servers on 2 IP addresses.

It is common - even advisable for name servers to be on a different domain to the the domains they support. Most registrars who provide DNS, and most large DNS providers do this. It reduces problems with glue records (special records handled by registrars required so domains can find themselves when the name servers are a subdomain), takes load off the root name servers, and are easier to maintain.

The A records of the nsX subdomains point to the IP addresses of the name servers they represent.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcorse you can keep them same with other server. Howerver, Main thing matters where the nameservers are pointed to.  If the name servers are pointed to correct IP/server (new server IP) then the name servers can be used.